Show that $f_F$ and $g^F$ are both non-negative measurable functions and that $\int f_F d\mu = \int g^F d\nu$
Let $(X, S, \mu)$ a measure space and $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \nu)$ the measure space with $\nu$ the counting measure. Let $F \in S \otimes \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.
Show that for $f_F: X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and $g^F: \mathbb{N} \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ defined as $f_F(x) = \nu(F_x)$ and $g^F(n) = \mu(F^n)$, it follows that $f_F$ is non-negative measurable function, $g^F$ is non-negative measurable function and
$$\int f_F d\mu = \int g^F d\nu$$
Here $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ denotes the extended reals and also
$$F_x: = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: (x, n) \in F\}, \quad \forall x \in X$$
$$F^n: = \{x \in X: (x, n) \in F\}, \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
Note that $(X, S, \mu)$ is not necessarily $\sigma-$finite, but $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \nu)$.
Proof.
We have that $g^F(n) = \mu(F^n) \ge 0$, for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since $\mu$ is measure. By the other hand, since $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ is the chosen $\sigma-$algebra on $\mathbb{N}$, $g^F$ is trivially measurable function, by definition.
We also have that $f_F(x) = \nu(F_x) \ge 0$, for each $x \in X$, since $\nu$ is measure. Now pick $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. If $\alpha < 0$,
$$(f_F)^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) = \{x \in X: f_F(x) > \alpha\} = \{x \in X: \nu(F_x) > \alpha\} = X \in S$$
Now suppose that $\alpha \ge 0$. Thus,
$$(f_F)^{-1}((\alpha, \infty)) = \{x \in X: f_F(x) > \alpha\} = \{x \in X: \nu(F_x) > \alpha\} = \bigcup_{n > \alpha} \{x \in X: \nu(F_x) = n\}$$
and I can't see why could $A_n := \{x \in X: \nu(F_x) = n\} \in S$ happen.
By another hand, I can’t niether see why the integral equality also holds:
$$\int_X f_F(x) d\mu(x) = \int_X \nu(F_x) d\mu(x)$$
$$\int_{\mathbb{N}} g^F(n) d\nu(n) = \int_{\mathbb{N}} \mu(F^n) d\nu(n) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mu(F^n)$$
I would appreciate some hints to finish this. Thanks!

$\int \phi d \nu=\sum_n \phi (n)$ for any non-negative measurable function $\phi$.

@geetha290krm Could you elaborate more please? I used that fact in my last equality but still don't see how to finish it.

For clarity: what do $F_x,F^n$ mean?

@Snoop I just wrote it, thanks!!
